# Closure of a set and and an "Open Ball" in a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and fix $t \in X$. Set $T = \{x\in X : ||x-t|| ≤ r\}$ and  $S= \{x\in X : ||x-t|| < r\}$.

Definition:  $\mathbf{y}\in\operatorname{Closure}(T)$ if there exists a sequence $\{t_n\}$ in $T$ converging to $\mathbf{y}$.

Now, if $\lim t_n = \mathbf{y}$ then $\lim t_n-t$ = $\mathbf{y}-t$.

Also $||t_n-t|| \leq r$ and so $\lim ||t_n-t|| =||\mathbf{y}-t|| \leq r$  and therefore $y \in T$. I am done.

If I try to apply this for S, I get that every closure point of $S$ is in $S$.
$\lim||s_n-t|| =||y-t|| < r$.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: You cannot deduce from $\|t_n-t\|<r$ that $\|y-t\| <r$. The strict inequality is, in general, false.

Answer (score 1):

When you take limits, inequalities become weak. So the assumption that $||s_n-t||<r$ for all $n$ only allows you to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}||s_n-t||\leq r$. (Think about $1-\frac{1}{n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$; every term is less than $1$, but the limit is not).

(As an aside, you have some norms missing in your proof that $T=\operatorname{Closure}(T)$.)